# UITableView on scroll doesn't call didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Tags: iphone

I have a UITableView with one section. If I click on a cell, the didSelectRowAtIndexPath is triggered as expected. but if the tableview has more rows than that can be shown in a single screen, and if I vertically scroll the tableview and click on a row, the didSelectRowAtIndexPath is not called. It is only triggered if i click on the same row one more time. Is this how the tableviews are supposed to function when you scroll? If not, is there something that I'm missing?
thanks for any help.

Comment: If the table is still scrolling the first touch will stop the scrolling in place without calling didSelectRowAtIndexPath. Is this what you meant? If not then please add more description and perhaps some relevant code snippets

Comment: I did a single tap to stop the scrolling, then tried selecting a row with another tap which did nothing. Is there a specific code/method that you want me to post? All I have is a simple tableview with around 20 rows, I have a breakpoint in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method which gets called only after i select the row twice...

Comment: Try pasting it all. Perhaps Tim is right...

Comment: I had this exact problem, where only the second tap provided my method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks Tim for your input. Adding the if condition did not help though. scrolling was disabled in nib file, enabling it fixed the issue. Thanks again!!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your cellForRowAtIndexPath is using dequeue wrong.

```
(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *SingleCellIdentifier = @"selectioncell";
    UITableViewCell *selectionCell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:SingleCellIdentifier];
    if(selectionCell == nil)    
        selectionCell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:SingleCellIdentifier] autorelease];  
        [selectionCell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue];
        [selectionCell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator];
    }   
    [[selectionCell textLabel] setText:[[possibleAnswers objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] answerText]]; 

}
```

The idea is that `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:`
 gives you a usable cell, but if none is available, it returns nil; if it's nil, you should allocate it yourself.  Your code was fetching the dequeued cell, but then ignoring it and simply allocing regardless of dequeue status.  Try this and see if it solves your issue.

Comment: i just veririfed my whole project for this method but couldn't find any